# Run dart unit tests in a flutter project

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart

I have a flutter project that implements a classic client/server model to obtain resources across the network.

I'm writing a series of unit tests to test the core network actions.

As this is a flutter project, when I run the unit tests visual code launches the device simulator and installs an apk.

This is a slow processes.

These unit tests have no dependancies on flutter.

Is there some way that I can get the unit tests to run as dart cli unit tests to speed up start time?

I would prefer to not move the code into a separate project.

Comment: How are you running your tests? `flutter test` does not need an apk or a simulator. The following is the output for tests at https://github.com/flutterigniter/flutter_data_stream_builder/blob/master/test/flutter_data_stream_builder_test.dart

`➜ flutter test   
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_data_stream_builder...         0.8s
00:05 +3: All tests passed!`

Comment: The Flutter test module supplies a headless Flutter runtime that doesn't need an emulator or a compiled apk. Unless you're running full end-to-end integration testing (in which case there's no way around installing on a device of some kind), Flutter testing should be quick and painless. Have you followed the testing procedure detailed on https://flutter.dev/docs/testing ?